# How to automatically assign a role based on email address domain?

Tags: 7, rules, hooks

How do I automatically assign a role to new users based on the email address domain?

For instance if the email address is `someone@examplecompany.com`, and the condition is that all users from `examplecompany.com` should always have the role `specialclient`. How do I acheive this?

I am using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), but there are no specific email conditions to be found. Can I create my own Rules Condition? If so, I would be very grateful for any tips on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could create your own (custom) Rules Condition. But in this case I don't think that's needed. The clue to what you're asking for, is a Rules Condition which is a "text comparison".

In that comparison, you use a regular expression to indicate "the email address should end with "`@examplecompany.com`".

For an example rule which also uses such RegEx-expressions, refer to the answer to "[How to use the Rules module to perform a simple anti-spam validation using specific keywords?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195799/how-to-use-the-rules-module-to-perform-a-simple-anti-spam-validation-using-speci/195866#195866)".

Be aware: I'm not a RegEx expert ..., but [here a few dozens of similar examples using a RegEx](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A39516%20rules%20regex%20requires) ...

**However**, I predict you'll have multiple domains/roles to be processed. So the real [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) fun starts when this (typical) question arises: "*I need to add something like a Rules Condition inside the Rules Actions, how can I do that?*"

To resolve this typical question, there are basically 2 approaches (that I am aware of):

- Use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module. For an example using the Conditional Rules module (for which there is not a lot of docu available), refer to my answer to the question "[How to prevent a node being saved when using the Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114955/how-to-prevent-a-node-being-saved-when-using-the-rules-module/178623#178623)".
- Rework the relevant part of your Rules Action(s) into performing a Rules Component. Because in a Rules Component, it is possible to also add Rules Conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Very useful and upvote. I will try to do as you suggest.

Comment: @TBJ Merci for the feedback ... you probably also want to try the 2nd part I just added ...